# Why do my post-build events work on one PC but not another?

Tags: c#, batch-file, build, cmd, post-build-event

I'm trying to run a post-build event to make my executable large address aware.  On my local PC the event works.  On the company's build machine it doesn't.  Here is all the post-build events:

```
call "$(VS110COMNTOOLS)..\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
editbin /largeaddressaware $(TargetPath)
$(SolutionDir)XClusterBuildCompleteEvent.bat $(SolutionDir) $(ConfigurationName) $(PlatformName) $(TargetDir) $(TargetName) 1
```

When run on the company's build machine I get the following error:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (4291): The command "call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools..\tools\vsvars32.bat" editbin
>   /largeaddressaware
>   D:\Builds_test\XTool\4.3.1_4GB_ClusterController\IBUAgent1\Binaries\ServiceRunner.exe
>   D:\Builds_test\XTool\4.3.1_4GB_ClusterController\IBUAgent1\CommonFileMover.bat
>   D:\Builds_test\XTool\4.3.1_4GB_ClusterController\IBUAgent1\ Release
>   D:\Builds_test\XTool\4.3.1_4GB_ClusterController\IBUAgent1\Binaries\
>   ServiceRunner XCluster" exited with code 255.

In looking into this some, apparently "call" is a batch file command and for whatever reason it doesn't always work in this situation.  So I tried replacing that with "cmd /c".  That got rid of the build error, but the executable wasn't altered to be large address aware.  It seems like it skipped the "editbin" portion.  The last post-build event still worked however.

I also tried not putting any command in front of the first post-build step, but that resulted in the same behavior as "cmd /c".

What do I need to do to either get "call" to work on the build machine or get the "editbin" step to run properly?

Comment: Does the build machine actually have Visual Studio 2012 (==11)? Many build machines do not have Visual Studio at all.

Comment: Yes, it has VS 2012.  I also checked the path and environmental variables for any discrepancies, and found none.